# iFrame height cannot be controlled , after using plyr and boostrap

Tags: html, css, iframe, height, plyr

As you can see the iframe height changes according to the video, I want the iframe video height to stay the same as I am making a website that allows people to watch youtube videos through the iframe from my website. You can notice the default size of the iframe when the page is about to load and the video loads it goes according to the video, so sometimes the height is too small or sometimes too big, I wanted to make it fixed.
https://codepen.io/harvir619/pen/QWmPvKX

```
'''<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.7.2/plyr.css" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      
        <div class="row m-0 mt-1"
            style="background-image:url('https://www.theasset.com/storage/eventimage/202206100949280.beyond-covid-blur.jpg'); background-size: cover;  ">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 p-0">
    <!--             {{-- <iframe style="border:none;"width="100%" height="100%" id="videoplayer" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1">
                </iframe> --}} -->
                <div class="plyr__video-embeds iframe1" id="player" height="100%" width="100%">
                    <iframe id="videoplayer" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1"
                        height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allowtransparency allow="autoplay"
                        scrolling="no" style=""></iframe>
                </div>
      <!--           {{-- THE VIDEOPLAYER SCRIPT --}} -->
                <script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.7.2/plyr.polyfilled.js"></script>
                <script>
                    // Change "{}" to your options:
                    // https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/#options
                    const player = new Plyr('#player', {});
    
                    // Expose player so it can be used from the console
                    window.player = player;
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 text-light">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-auto" style="  margin-inline: auto; ">
                        <div class="video-wrapper">
                            <div class="videos">
                                <a class="video"
                                    onclick="player.source = { type: 'video',sources: [ { src: 'IlJ_NAvIhX4', provider: 'youtube', },],}">
                                    <span></span>
                                    <img src="{{ show_cf_image($the_asset_talk[0]->art_profile_image) }}"
                                        id="{{ basename($the_asset_talk[0]->art_video_url) }}"
                                        vid="{{ basename($the_asset_talk[0]->art_id) }}"
                                        alt="{{ $the_asset_talk[0]->art_videotitle }}" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col ">
                        <h2 class="text-center">Recommended</h2>
                        <br>
                        <h5>{{ $the_asset_talk[0]->art_videotitle }}</h5>
                        <p>
                            orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                            et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-auto" style="  margin-inline: auto; ">
                        <div class="video-wrapper">
                            <div class="videos">
                                <a class="video"
                                    onclick="player.source = { type: 'video',sources: [ { src: 'IlJ_NAvIhX4', provider: 'youtube', },],}">
                                    <span></span>
                                    <img src="{{ show_cf_image($the_asset_talk[1]->art_profile_image) }}"
                                        id="{{ basename($the_asset_talk[1]->art_video_url) }}"
                                        vid="{{ basename($the_asset_talk[1]->art_id) }}"
                                        alt="{{ $the_asset_talk[1]->art_videotitle }}" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h2 class="text-center">Most Watched</h2>
                        <br>
                        <h5>{{ $the_asset_talk[1]->art_videotitle }}</h5>
                        <p>
                            orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                            et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    enter code here
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try style="min-height: 50vh; max-height:50vh;" on your div with id="player"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: min and max helped control the height of the iframe

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I quite understood what you are looking for exactly, but try creating a new `style.css` file and add the following code:

```
.plyr__video-embed iframe,
.plyr__video-wrapper--fixed-ratio video,
.plyr__video-wrapper.plyr__video-embed {
    min-height: 700px !important;
    max-height: 700px !important;
    height: 700px !important;
}
```

try adjusting the height to your liking

Comment: check out the codepen link and try changing the videos by clicking the links on right, you will see what I mean by the height changing according to the video

Comment: this didn't work because i had to adjust the size of the div instead of the iframe